# Trabajo en ETL para archivos extensión.json.gz.zip

Tags: json, visualización-de-datos, etl, gzip

No encuentro el repositorio para poder ver los archivos extensión "archivo.json.gz.zip" me larga error y estoy trabajando en un ETL para ver la documentación, procesarla para continuar con el EDA.

he usado el siguiente código, no me larga error, pero no peudo avanzar en mi ETL para posteriormente trabajarlo en EDA.

```
# Importamos libreráis necesarias
import json
import gzip

# Función para leer un archivo JSON comprimido
def leer_archivo_json_comprimido(archivo):
    with gzip.open(archivo, "rb") as f:
        datos = f.readlines()
    return datos

# Función para leer un objeto JSON
def leer_objeto_json(datos):
    return json.loads(datos.decode("utf-8"))

# Rutas de los archivos
ruta_steam_games = "C:/Users/Esteban García/OneDrive/Documentos/LABs/Proy Ind N° 1 Machine Learning Operations MLOps/PI_ML_OPS/steam_games.json.gz"

# Leer el archivo JSON
datos = leer_archivo_json_comprimido(ruta_steam_games)

# Iterar sobre los objetos JSON
objetos_json = []
for dato in datos:
    objetos_json.append(leer_objeto_json(dato))

# Imprimir los objetos JSON
print(objetos_json)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "me larga error ".. que error?